# Loading spinner on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have an ajax script to fetch a query file and load new content from that file on database update.
However how would I go about adding a loading spinner to the script?

```js
< div id = "AjaxLoader" >
  < h1 > Loading < /h1>
</div >
  < div id = "feed_main_load" >


  < /div>
```

```html
var $loading = $('#AjaxLoader').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $loading.hide();
  });


 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#feed_main_load").load("elements/feedloadtest.php");
       var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
          $("#feed_main_load").load("elements/feedloadtest.php?" + 1*new Date());
       }, 60000);
    });
```

Comment: before the ajax call sow the spinner after the ajax call is ready just hide it.

Comment: i mean use just simple DOM element (text for example) and try it, later you could replace it with GIF image or something.

Comment: I updated my post. Would that work?

Comment: well, i do not know exactly, i have done something like that before but i do not know your plot so just try little this and that. look around internet must be examples there also in SO i have seen questions about spinners.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to show the spinner before you call $.load,

and hide it in completion callback.

You have here a full snippet:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(img).hide();

       $("#feed_main_load").load("elements/feedloadtest.php");
       $(img).show();

       var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
          $("#feed_main_load").load("elements/feedloadtest.php?" + 1*new Date(), function(){
   $(img).hide();
});
       }, 60000);
    });
```

```html
<img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/135058/screenshots/950508/spinny_2x.gif" width=64 height=64/>
<div id="feed_main_load">


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work however the loading spinner doesn't seem to stop and actually show the content

Comment: It's in stackoverflow sandbox. In your site is should work

Comment: Would this cause it to stop working. I have an ajax script on the main index page which loads another file with ajax in. And that 2nd file contains this script